# Navigation Drawer with Master Detail flow never shows two panes

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, master-detail

I'm trying to incorporate a master-detail flow along side a navigation drawer pattern. I've followed the instructions given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21036841/how-to-implement-navigation-drawer-with-fragments-master-detail/26597742#26597742). This works for displaying one pane, but for these steps her instructions state to add the relevant code to the MainActivity, which in my case is NavigationDrawerActivity:

> (5B) Copy part of code from onCreate in ItemListActivity and paste it
>   to onCreate in MainActivity.This part:

```
    if (findViewById(R.id.item_detail_container) != null) {
    // The detail container view will be present only in the
    // large-screen layouts (res/values-large and
    // res/values-sw600dp). If this view is present, then the
    // activity should be in two-pane mode.
    mTwoPane = true;

    // In two-pane mode, list items should be given the
    // 'activated' state when touched.
    ((ItemListFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.item_list))
            .setActivateOnItemClick(true);
}
```

> (5C) Also copy onItemSelected method from ItemListActivity and paste
>   it into MainActivity. You will already have an onItemSelected method
>   if you told Eclipse to "add unimplemented methods" in response to the
>   error that would have been raised after Step 5A. If you don't, copy
>   over the whole method. (this step edited in response to a question in
>   comments):

```
if (mTwoPane) {
    // In two-pane mode, show the detail view in this activity by
    // adding or replacing the detail fragment using a
    // fragment transaction.
    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    arguments.putString(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
    ItemDetailFragment fragment = new ItemDetailFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(arguments);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment)
            .commit();

} else {
    // In single-pane mode, simply start the detail activity
    // for the selected item ID.
    Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, ItemDetailActivity.class);
    detailIntent.putExtra(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
    startActivity(detailIntent);
}
```

This line:

> if (findViewById(R.id.item_detail_container) != null) {

is always null. I don't think I need it in the onCreate method of the NavigationDrawerActivity, since the master-detail fragment isn't created until that item is selected from my navigation menu, but I'm not sure where to put it. I've tried putting it after the fragment is replaced and committed, but that doesn't seem to work either. For clarity, what I'm trying to achieve is a navigation menu where most fragments are going to be master-details types. Please let me know if there is anything that is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add layout for landscape in project? Android have **layout-land** resource folder that includes layout for landscape.

So you need to add two layouts to use that process.

**layout**          resource folder contains layout files to use in normal orientation

**layout-land**     resource folder contains layout files to use in landscape orientation

So,

layout from **res/layout**  will include only **list container** for list

layout from **res/layout-land** will include **list container** and **item_detail_container**

Android get layout from **res/layout** for landscape orientation when there is no **res/layout-land**. And your layout doesn't include that view. That's why your condition is always being null.

If you add **res/layout-land** with layout that contains two view, it will solve your error. Pls check back your sample. :)

Thanks

Comment: I m not clear now. How do you want to do? Your code is for this design. If phone is on Portrait, app will only show list and onItemClick will go to detail page. If phone is landscape, app will show two layout as you told.

Comment: I'm testing this on an actual tablet with a width over 600dp. I know this because other layouts I've created are correct on this device. When I add the master-detail activity, the wizard creates a layout for sw600dp. Just for the sake of completeness, I copied this into the layout-land folder. I never get the two-view layout. I've created an empty master-detail project in Android Studio and it works fine. As soon as I add the nav drawer in, it no longer shows the two-view layout, even though I've followed the instructions in the linked answer. I don't know why or what I could be missing.