# Action Bar UP navigation Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I'm developing an app which has a navigation drawer. Although I don't have any previous experience with fragments I could implement navigation drawer successfully. Now my problem is, I want to have an Action Bar back button. I have tried this before for activities. But now the problem is I have a fragment which has a click event inside it. When the user clicks the button it goes to an activity which has list view inside it. Now I want to go back to the previous fragment using action bar up button. How can I do it? It's working properly when I press back button on my phone.

I have implemented onOptionsItemSelected as below in my list view activity. When I press action bar up button it goes to the login window. Not where I wanted it to go.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        Intent upIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
        if (NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(this, upIntent)) {
            // This activity is NOT part of this app's task, so create a new task
            // when navigating up, with a synthesized back stack.
            TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
                    // Add all of this activity's parents to the back stack
                    .addNextIntentWithParentStack(upIntent)
                    // Navigate up to the closest parent
                    .startActivities();
        } else {
            // This activity is part of this app's task, so simply
            // navigate up to the logical parent activity.
            NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Can anybody provide some help on the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this post: [Using ActionBar Up Navigation in master/detail fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472044/using-actionbar-up-navigation-in-master-detail-fragments) you can find you're answer for this problem.

I think you must working with the FragmentManager instead of the Activity.

Comment: yes it worked.... thank you for your help.. and i have a different question to ask from you.. if you can tell me, can i use assync task inside an adapter class ?  because my application crashes sometimes when it runs the assync task..first and seccond attempts hopefully works fine. but when i attempt to run some task several times , it crashes  :(

Comment: nice to hear that it works. The Best for you're other Problem is, that you start an other topic for this. With Code, ErrorLog and the process (where it crash).