# setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) opens Options Menu

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, back-stack, fragment-backstack

I have a fragment `MyProfile` *(consists info about a logged user)* which I want to be used by fragments `Team` *(consists info about all team members)*. When I use `MyProfile` for `Team` fragment, I need `up` button. I  read documentation [guide](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral), tried all from [up navigation inside fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=up%20navigation%20inside%20fragment) and stopped on [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472044/using-actionbar-up-navigation-in-master-detail-fragments).

The problem is instead of going back to the previous fragment in my case it just opens the options menu.

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_team) {
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new TeamFragment())
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }
```

**TeamFragment**

```
public class TeamFragment extends Fragment {

private String LOG_TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
private ListView teamList;
private android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager;

public TeamFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setActionBarTitle("Team");

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_announcement, container, false);
    final SwipeRefreshLayout swipeToUpdate = rootView.findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);

    teamList = rootView.findViewById(R.id.announcements_list);
    getTeamFromAPI(Contract.TEAM);

    teamList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ImageView avatar = view.findViewById(R.id.team_img);
            TextView fullname = view.findViewById(R.id.team_fullname);
            TextView jobtitle = view.findViewById(R.id.team_jobtitle);
            TextView email = view.findViewById(R.id.team_email);

            avatar.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap bitmap = avatar.getDrawingCache();
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
            byte[] bAvatar = baos.toByteArray();
             //when team member i replace here current fragment with profile fragment
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Fragment fragment = ProfileFragment.newInstance(String.valueOf(fullname.getText()),
                    String.valueOf(jobtitle.getText()),
                    String.valueOf(email.getText()), bAvatar);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, "MEMBER_PROFILE")
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}

private void getTeamFromAPI(String url) {
    //fetch team members from database
}
```

}

Place where I try return back to TeamFragment

**ProfileFragment**

```
    public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment{

private String LOG_TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
private String mFullname;
private String mTitle;
private String mEmail;
private byte[] mAvatar;

private android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager;
private ActionBar actionBar;
private View rootView;

public ProfileFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static ProfileFragment newInstance(String name, String title, String email, byte[] avatar) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("fullname", name);
    bundle.putString("title", title);
    bundle.putString("email",email);
    bundle.putByteArray("avatar", avatar);

    ProfileFragment fragment = new ProfileFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    return fragment;
}

private void readBundle(Bundle bundle) {
    if (bundle != null) {
        this.mFullname = bundle.getString("fullname");
        this.mTitle = bundle.getString("title");
        this.mEmail = bundle.getString("email");
        this.mAvatar = bundle.getByteArray("avatar");
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    // Sets "up navigation" for both phone/tablet configurations
    actionBar = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_announcement, container, false);
    ListView listView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.announcements_list);

    SwipeRefreshLayout swipe = rootView.findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);
    swipe.setEnabled(false);


    readBundle(getArguments());
    ArrayList<ProfileObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new ProfileObject(mFullname, mTitle,mEmail,mAvatar));

    ProfileAdapter adapter = new ProfileAdapter(getContext(), list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:

            Log.e(LOG_TAG+"/onOptionsItemSelected","Pressed: "+item.getItemId());
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ProfileFragment member_profile = (ProfileFragment)fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("MEMBER_PROFILE");
            fragmentTransaction.remove(member_profile).commit();
            fragmentManager.popBackStack();
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

}

But as I already said it only the opens options menu. Did I make a somewhere conceptual mistake?

**UPDATE:** Problem inside `onOptionsItemSelected`. If add

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Log.e(LOG_TAG+"/onOptionsItemSelected","Pressed: "+item.getItemId());
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and click on back arrow nothing will be in Logcat.

Comment: `return true` at the end of the switch case?

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh what should be there then?

Comment: Are you trying to go back from ProfileFragment to TeamFragment ? and those aren't nested fragments right?

Comment: @adityakamble49 right, that's what I want to. Yes, I just replace one fragment by another. Why? I guess problem inside `Profile` fragment in `onOptionsItemSelected`...When I add `Log.d("..","..")` after `case R.id.home:` nothing happens in my Logcat

Answer (score 1):

As per your code you have handled `onOptionsItemSelected()` for `R.id.home` but I see you are using `ActionBar` **back button** which is provided by **Android UI** itself

```
actionBar = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

In this case **Home Button** is referenced as `android.R.id.home` and **NOT** `R.id.home`

This is the reason you are not getting any update in Logcat too (as you mentioned in comments).

Update your switch case as below and **replace** `R.id.home` with `android.R.id.home`

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home: // <- Update this

            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ProfileFragment member_profile = (ProfileFragment)fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("MEMBER_PROFILE");
            fragmentTransaction.remove(member_profile).commit();
            fragmentManager.popBackStack();
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
            return true;

        default:
             return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, but still, it isn't a case. I deleted `android.` as one of possible solution from that list (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=up+navigation+inside+fragment)

Comment: Otherwise, It's still opening options menu

Comment: Other reason might be because you didn't added `ProfileFragment` in backstack

Comment: Indeed! Thanks! But still, it just opens options menu instead of going back

Comment: I think ` setHasOptionsMenu(true);` method overrides back button from activity. Remove that method and try if back button works